# Is there anything like Project Sprouts but implemented in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, apache-flex

Since our entire build system is written in Python, I'm wondering if there is anything like [Sprouts](http://projectsprouts.org/) that I could leverage to integrate Flex builds / development into our codebase?

Sprouts looks nice and all, but I don't want to introduce another build-time dependency to our projects (namely Ruby).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is anything similar for Python.

It looks like Sprouts is made up of a lot of [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) build files, so you could try to roll your own build system in Python using tools like [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/), [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9/), [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/docs/index.html) recipes, [paster templates](http://pythonpaste.org/script/developer.html#templates), etc. That would give you the ability to generate new projects like Sprouts does.

Overall I wouldn't worry too much about adding Ruby as a dependency. If it does what you need then you'll save a lot of time by using it instead of hunting for something written in Python (or worse yet rewriting its functionality).